# What is argument push order

Tags: assembly, x86, arguments, calling-convention, stack-memory

I'm learning Assembly language. What exactly is argument push order? I understand it's how arguments are pushed to the stack but **what does the *left* and *right* part mean**? Left or right of what?

Or is this merely to do with the way the command is semantically written, i.e.:

```
mov ebp, esp             ;esp is moved into ebp, right to left.
```

Is this correct or could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 19):

The processor doesn't know 'function arguments'.  Therefore when you want to write `f(a,b,c)`, you really need to push the arguments 'somewhere'.

How and where to push them is mere convention.  I know that on most x86 machines, function arguments are pushed on the stack from right to left, i.e. first c, then b, then a.

```
push c
push b
push a
call f
```

Pushing to the stack would, on x86, decrease the stack 'top' with a word.  Three words have been pushed, and the return address, so the called function can use `top + 1*W` for `a`, `top + 2*W` for `b` and `top + 3*W` for `c`.

You could as well establish a convention that says: first two arguments are in registers `ebx` and `ecx`, rest are on the stack.  As long as the caller and callee agree, you're fine.

Comment: Where did `ebx-1` come from?  If those are supposed to be addresses, `push` decrements the stack pointer by 4 (or 8 in 64-bit mode), so each stack slot is 4 or 8 bytes apart, like `ebx - 4` (c), `ebx - 8` (b) etc.  And that's only if EBX = ESP right before those pushes.  That's unusual; if you were going to do that with any register, it would be EBP.  But the *callee* `f` can't assume anything about where the caller left EBP relative to its incoming stack args.  It needs to look above its return address, and `[esp+4]` (a), `[esp+8]` (b), etc.  Or higher offsets after pushing anything.

Comment: But yes, your final paragraph is correct, register calling conventions work, like `fastcall` passing in ECX, EDX, or gcc's `regparm(3)` passing in EAX, EDX, ECX.  And your earlier stuff is correct about pushing the first arg last, so it's at the lowest address.

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  I should have left it more high level.

Comment: That partially fixes the problem, but `c` is at a higher address than `a`, since it was pushed earlier, before two `stack_pointer-=stack_width` from two pushes.  The standard location for a frame pointer to point is right below the return address, in which case `frame+2*W` for `a`, `frame+3*W` for `b`.  But regardless of where your reference point is, `c`'s address is higher, + more not - more.

Comment: OMG ;(.  I guess it's unconventional to define `W` as `-4`...  Note to self: start a compiler backend hobby project.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to [xtofl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9141617/257111)'s explanation you might like to have a look at this table of [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions). What you'll note, with regards to argument order is that *almost all* of the arguments are pushed on right to left (rightmost argument is pushed first) with the exception of Pascal.

Another scenario xtofl doesn't cover are register arguments - some ABIs require that some arguments are in registers *as opposed to* on the stack. On a `x86_64` system, for example, the function:

```
int add3(int a, int b, int c)
```

will put arguments:

```
a -> rdi
b -> rsi
c -> rdx
```

Specifically, this would look like (Intel syntax):

```
mov     rdi, [source-of-a]
mov     rsi, [source-of-b]
mov     rdx, [source-of-c]
call    add3
```

So the registers are filled up from the register list *left to right* and then the stack is used *right to left*.

As xtofl says, it doesn't matter what you do provided the caller and the callee agree - clearly, however, if the caller and the callee *disagree* that'll cause incompatibility problems and this is actually a concern not only for assembler, but for higher level languages too - luckily, compilers largely operate right to left. For further reading, you might find the callee/caller cleanup of the stack interesting - and note how it was standardised to one method for `x86_64`.

You don't say you're using `x86` - your architecture will most certainly have a standard calling convention as working without it is difficult.

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you. That was very helpful and I understand it much better now! Thanks a mil!!

Comment: See [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989) for details on the x86 calling conventions for 32-bit and 64-bit Linux (and other non-Windows x86-64 systems)